# How to return an entire json object when grep'ing jq output?

Tags: grep, jq

I have this json file - test.json

```
{"type":"RECORD","record":{"key_A": "apples","key_B":"bananas"}}
```

Then I do

```
cat test.json | jq '. | {first_fruit: .record.key_A,second_fruit:.record.key_B}' | grep "bananas"
  "second_fruit": "bananas"
```

So it only shows me the "second_fruit":"bananas" line. Is there a way to return the object that contains that grep match? So it should return

```
{
  "first_fruit": "apples",
  "second_fruit": "bananas"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` filters on the textual representation. Stay in `jq` to perform a logical filter, e.g. using `select` and `any` to forward only those inputs for which at least one (`any`) field value (`.[]`) matches (`==`) the given string.

```sh
jq '
  {first_fruit: .record.key_A,second_fruit:.record.key_B}
  | select(any(.[]; . == "bananas"))
'
```

```json
{
  "first_fruit": "apples",
  "second_fruit": "bananas"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MPagvQI6GR)

Or more efficiently, as @peak [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72164489/how-to-return-an-entire-json-object-when-greping-jq-output/72164522#comment127503635_72164522), you may want to select first and then shape the output:

```sh
.record | select(any(.[]; . == "bananas"))
| {first_fruit: .key_A, second_fruit: .key_B}
```

Instead of finding exact matches with `==`, you can also use `contains` for partial matches, or `test` for a full regex test.

```sh
select(any(.[]; contains("bananas")))
```

```sh
select(any(.[]; test("bananas")))
```

Comment: Or more efficiently, select first: `.record | select( any(.[]; . == "bananas")) |  {first_fruit: .key_A, second_fruit: .key_B}`